# Server2go not supporting .htaccessfile

Tags: .htaccess, server2go

I have downloaded and installed latest version of server2go. I put my all files in htdocs folder with .htaccess file where I have rewritten various rules...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^Home$ index.php
```

Then I tried 127.0.0.1/Home in the browser; it didn't work. However 127.0.0.1/index.php is working!!!

I have enabled module rewrite in httpd.conf file & also written "Override All" in it!!

Comment: try replacing "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>" for "RewriteEngine On"?

Comment: tried...but not working!!!

Comment: where have you set override all, and what have you done to enable mod rewrite?

Comment: changed httpd.conf file in both direcotries config_tpl & apache/conf ...

Comment: what did you change... from what, to what. Was the text you changed in a scope e.g. <Directory ".....">. Add this to the question.